# save html table in mysql

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, database

Have a website about financial planning. A user can input different values and cell colors in the HTML table. Thus, the HTML tables must be maintained exactly. How do I save the entire HTML table (with values and colors) in MySQL database using db? I don't know PHP, but I'm a beginner in JavaScript and Python. I know there must be a table field of type BLOB, but what do I put in the HTML file. What do I put in SQL?

Comment: please don't try and save your html to a db. just save the values, and maybe the values of the colors and dynamically create the html table when you need it from the data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to save entire `html` table to the database since you may have to do calculations on each cell values.

Instead values can be stored in the database

Example for 2 columns (1 for value 1 for color)

**Database**

```
itemName | itemColor 
---------|---------- 
php      | blue
js       | green
```

**PHP**

Contruct a table and iterate through the mysql result and display each row

```
while($node = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='background:$node[itemColor]'>$node[itemName]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

See this [tutorial](https://davidwalsh.name/html-mysql-php)

Comment: The priority is the colors. I don't know php at all. Never learned the language. Do you know in another language? Maybe javascript or python?